# Windows batch for loop iterates only once

Tags: batch-file

Given the following for loop from a batch file, why is this only printing A? I have also tried with "tokens=1*"

```
set str=A/B/C/D/E/F
for /F "delims=/" %%S in ("%str%") do (
    echo %%~S
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delims option defines the delimiters to split *each* line into seperate tokens.
The tokens itself can be accesses by succesive parameters.

```
set str=A/B/C/D/E/F
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=/" %%S in ("%str%") do (
    echo %%~S %%T %%U %%V %%W
)
```

This will split *each* line, but you want to handle `A/B/C/D/E/F` as seperate lines.

This can be done by injecting linefeeds

```
set LF=^


REM ** Two empty lines are required
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "str=A/B/C/D/E/F"
for %%L in ("!LF!") DO set "str=!str:/=%%~L!"
for /F "delims=/" %%S in ("!str!") do (
    echo %%~S
)
```

The line `for %%L in ("!LF!") DO set "str=!str:/=%%~L!"` replaces `/` with linefeeds